# Not able to update data in mongoDB using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

When I try to change the status of a blog , the status is not updating in database. Status is string field and is initially stored as 0 in database

```
api.post('/statuschange', function(req, res){
    Blog.find({_id: req.query.blog_id}).update({$set:{'status': req.body.status}}, function (err, status) {

            if(err){
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }

            if(req.body.status == '1') {
                res.json('Blog added')
                    return;
                }

            if(req.body.status == '-1'){
                 res.json('Blog not added');
                     return;
                 }
    });
})
```

api is working successfully on postman

factory file

```
angular.module('blogfact', ['authService'])

.factory('blogFactory', function($http, AuthToken){

var factory = {};
var token = AuthToken.getToken();

factory.changestatus = function(info, callback){

     $http({
        url: 'api/statuschange',
        method:'POST',
        headers:{'x-access-token':token},
        params:{'blog_id': info},
    })
        .success(function(response){
            callback(response)
        })
}
return factory
})
```

the controller file

```
angular.module('blogCtrl', ['blogfact']);

.controller('BlogController', function(blogFactory, $routeParams){

    var that=this;
    blogid = $routeParams.id;
    var getthatBlog = function(){
        blogFactory.getthatBlog(blogid, function(data){
        //console.log('[CONTROLLER] That Blog:',data);
        that.blog = data;
    })
}
    this.changestatus = function(info){
        blogFactory.changestatus(info, function(data){
            getthatBlog();
        })
        }
    })
```

html file

```
<div ng-controller="BlogController as blog">
<textarea ng-model="blog.status"></textarea>
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="blog.changestatus(blog._id)">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you watched your browser's console for any client/server-side error.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Surely it's not *Angular* that is "updating the database"? Do you perhaps have a problem with the data being sent? Or is it a problem with server side code? (Also, it'd help if you edit the question and format the code for readability.)

Comment: @AhmadBaktashHayeri hi.. I am new to MEAN.. but whenever i go to the html page for changing the status.. the browser console show the info of blog which is returning from the blogfactory

Comment: @Jeroen i couldn't understand that how is data sent to html file or what should i pass in html file to update the status.. the api is working fine postman

Answer (score 1):

If your question is regarding the value in MongoDB not being updated, well it seams it is due to the `status` data missing in your `POST` request.

I recommend that in your HTML, send the whole `blog` object so that you have the blog's *status* as well:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="blog.changestatus(blog)">Submit</button>
```

Then in your `blogFactory` add the *data* as such:

```
$http({
    url: 'api/statuschange',
    method:'POST',
    headers:{'x-access-token':token},
    params:{'blog_id': info._id},
    data: {status: info.status}   // <==
})
```

Now, you should be able get the blog status data in NodeJS server back-end via *`req.body.status`*.

### Update

Try the following with mongoose's `update` method:

```
Blog.update({_id: req.query.blog_id}, {status: req.body.status}, function(err, numAffected){
   ...
});
```

Or, alternatively:

```
Blog.findOne({_id: req.query.blog_id}, function(err, blog){
    blog.status = req.body.status;
    blog.save();
});
```

Comment: still not working.. in console.log(req.body) in api .. the console is showing {status: the value which i entered(1 or 0 or -1).. but is not updated in my db

Comment: This means at least you are getting the `status` in the body. Better log the `err` as well to see if there is any DB error while updating. If you're using `mongoose`, it's preferable to use `.update` instead of your approach.

Comment: yes i'm using mongoose and can't understand where the error is..!!

Comment: A tip: Try a mongoosish approach as in an update to my answer and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your are sending the data in `params` and getting the data from `req.body`.
   You should use `req.query` or `req.param`. Else, Send the data on body like below,

   $http({
      url: 'api/statuschange',
      method: 'POST',
      params: { 'blog_id': info },
      data: { 'status': 1 }
    })
2. Your are passing 1 parameter in client side and getting two parameters on server side(`req.body.status`, req.query.blog_id)
3. Where is the `token` value from ?

Check the simplified way to test your code
http://plnkr.co/edit/tyFDpXw2i0poICwt0ce0

Comment: the problem still persists..!! i am not understanding that how the new value (which i am entering) is being sent

Comment: change `this.changestatus` to `that.changestatus`

Comment: Had you checked that you're getting value on node.js ?

Comment: i don't know what exactly what you are trying to say.. the api is working successfully in postman

Comment: Just print `console.log(req.body)` inside your function `api.post('/statuschange', function(req, res){` and then restart the server and then click `Submit` button, Check what value your getting.

Comment: i am getting an empty array { }

Comment: Are you doing authentication on token ? , If not comment the line and try again `//headers:{'x-access-token':token}`

Comment: yes i'm doing authentication on token.. the status can only be changed only after login so to authenticate i'm doing this

Comment: What is the value for this `token` ? `headers:{'x-access-token':token}` You didn't declared anywhere.

Comment: Comment once and try again :P

Comment: i have added a middleware in my api.js file.. only after login those api can be accessed..!!

Answer (score 0):

Angular let's you modify collection data on the client-side, but to actually update it on your server you need to notify the server of your changes (via API).

There are a few ways to do this, but if you want seamless updating from client-side to server maybe give meteor a try.

http://www.angular-meteor.com/

https://www.meteor.com/